# Могу ли я через реф или другим спомоб получить компонент что скрыт методом v-show( display:none) в Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js

Есить у меня компонент модлаки, и мне обработать его через реф, перед открытиям модалки, но выдает ошибку потому что дом елемент скрыт, как я могу достать метод например через реф,или другим способом, когда компонент display none, emit мне не подходит

Comment: _«выдает ошибку потому что дом елемент скрыт»_ - какую именно? _«как я могу достать метод например через реф,или другим способом, когда компонент display none»_ - через реф и можешь... в чем именно затруднения с вариантом "через реф"? (в комментарии отвечать не надо, надо дополнить этой информацией сам вопрос, чтобы он стал более конкретным)

Comment: @yar85 this.$refs.moda.show() - в консоле выдает что show() undefined/ примера щас нет, так как код на работе, когда компонент скрыт тогда вылазит ошибка show  undefined. а когда display block то все ок